# Cuda Project Not Compiling

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, cuda

I have compiled my cuda project using visual studio 2010. I have countered an error stated:

student_func.cu(65): error C2059: syntax error : '<'

The line where error occurs is when the kernel function is called:

```
rgba_to_greyscale<<< gridSize, blockSize >>>(d_rgbaImage, d_greyImage, numRows, numCols);
```

and here is the code for student_func.cu:

```
#include "reference_calc.cpp"
#include "utils.h"
#include <stdio.h>



__global__ 
void rgba_to_greyscale(const uchar4* const rgbaImage,
                   unsigned char* const greyImage,
                   int numRows, int numCols)
{

}


void your_rgba_to_greyscale(const uchar4 * const h_rgbaImage, uchar4 * const d_rgbaImage,
                        unsigned char* const d_greyImage, size_t numRows, size_t numCols)
{
    //You must fill in the correct sizes for the blockSize and gridSize
    //currently only one block with one thread is being launched
    const dim3 blockSize(1, 1, 1);  //TODO
    const dim3 gridSize( 1, 1, 1);  //TODO
    rgba_to_greyscale<<< gridSize, blockSize >>>(d_rgbaImage, d_greyImage, numRows, numCols);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
}
```

Comment: Does the file containing this code have a `.cpp` extension?

Comment: yes, the main file containing main function... The problem I think, is some link is missing in project properties as I have another project which I made by editing cuda Sample project and it works fine!

Comment: Also commenting out this line builds the project successfully!

Answer (score 1):

Please, have first a look at this guide on [how to integrate CUDA in a Visual Studio C++ project](http://www.orangeowlsolutions.com/archives/109).

Also, you should organize the code so that:

- **.h, .cpp, .c, .hpp** files should not contain CUDA code (like `__device__` functions and the kernel call in your case). However, in these files you can call CUDA APIs (for example, `cudaMalloc`, `cudaMemcpy`, etc.). These files are compiled by a compiler other than NVCC.
- **.cuh, .cu** files should contain the CUDA code. These files are compiled by NVCC.

As an example, suppose to have a GPU-based FDTD code. I usually do the following (Visual Studio 2010).

- **main.cpp** file, including CPU-GPU memory transfers;
- **FDTD.cu**, including an `extern "C" void E_update(...)` function which contains the kernel `<<< >>>` call;
- **main.h** file, including the `extern "C" void E_update(...)` prototype;
- **FDTD.cuh**, including the `__global__ void E_update_kernel(...)` function.